# Why is the reduct theory a theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

My textbook says that if $T\subseteq \mathcal{L}$ is a theory, $\mathcal{L}_0\subseteq \mathcal{L}$, and $T_0:=T\cap\mathcal{L}_0$, then $T_0$ is a theory and called the *reduct theory* in the language $\mathcal{L}_0$. A theory is defined as a set of sentences (formulas without free variables) that is also deductively closed, so that $T\vDash\alpha \Leftrightarrow \alpha\in T$.

Now say we have a set of sentences $S$ that is not yet a theory because it derives one more sentence: $S\vDash\phi$ and $\phi\notin S$. For all other sentences, the closure property holds. Clearly, $T:=S\cup \{\phi\}$ is a theory. Now pick $\mathcal{L}_0=S$. Then $T_0=T\cap S=S$, but $S$ is not a theory.

Where am I going wrong here?

**Edit:** I think my error may be here:

> Clearly, $T:=S\cup \{\phi\}$ is a theory.

After all, $T$ could now be able to derive yet more sentences now that $\phi$ is part of it. But still, I don't have any idea how to prove that $T_0$ is deductively closed.

Comment: I guess that, by abuse of notation, $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of all sentences in a language $\mathcal{L}$. So, $\mathcal{L}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ is not only a subset of $\mathcal{L}$, but the set of all sentences in the language $\mathcal{L}_0$, which is a sublanguage of $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Otherwise, your argument is essentially correct. Let $T$ be a theory, with $\varphi \in T$, and let $S = T \smallsetminus \{\varphi\}$. Now, $S \models \varphi$ (because $T \models \varphi \land \varphi$, so $\varphi \land \varphi \in T$ and hence $\varphi \land \varphi \in S$) but $\varphi \notin S$, with $S = T \cap S$ because $S \subseteq T$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Ah yes that must be it! Thank you very much, that makes it a trivial matter.

Comment: Ah I found a sentence in the book saying that the usage of the letter $\mathcal{L}$ will always refer to the set of all formulas in a given language. Everything is fine then.

Comment: Are you able now to prove that $T \cap \mathcal{L}_0$ is a theory?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I am, I will add the answer here later today for completeness.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: what's the abuse of notation?

Comment: @RobArthan - $\mathcal{L}$ is both a language (essentially, the set of symbols) and the set of sentences in that language. Also, $\mathcal{L}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ has to be intended as "the set of sentences in the language $\mathcal{L}_0$ is included in the set of sentences of the language $\mathcal{L}$" (a priori, the OP does not assume anything about $\mathcal{L}_0$, so $\mathcal{L}_0$ might be just a subset of sentences of $\mathcal{L}$).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: I thought that is what you were going to reply: many authors (wisely in my opinion) distinguish between a signature (which they call a signature rather than a language) and the language it generates (which they call a language). With that convention there is no abuse of notation in the question. As the OP hasn't identified the textbook, we can't comment on whether it is abusing notation (although I agree that the statement ${\cal L}_0 \subseteq \cal L$ needs clarification if languages are not identified with signatures).

Comment: @RobArthan The book in question is "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Wolfgang Rautenberg, and you are right that there is actually no abuse of notation since the usage of the letter $\mathcal{L}$ in any context has been stated to mean either the signature of a language, the language or the set of all formulas in the language, depending on context. However, it is fair to assume that Taroccoesbrocco's comment made the assumption that I had read the book more carefully in which case I wouldn't have had to ask this question unless there had been an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @Taroccoesbrocco has pointed out, $\mathcal{L}_0$ refers to the set of all formulas in the language $\mathcal{L}_0$, so it is not just any subset of $\mathcal{L}$:

$$
\mathcal{L}_0\vDash\alpha\Leftrightarrow\alpha\in\mathcal{L}_0
$$

Now on to the proof that $T_0:=T\cap\mathcal{L}_0$ is a theory.

It is clear that $T_0$ only contains sentences, because $T$ only contains sentences and thus the same is true for $T_0\subseteq T$. What is left to prove is that $T_0$ is deductively closed:

$$
\begin{align*}
T_0\vDash\alpha&\Rightarrow T\vDash\alpha\ \mathrm{and}\ \mathcal{L}_0\vDash\alpha\text{  (follows from monotonicity of }\vDash\text{)}\\
&\Rightarrow \alpha\in T\ \mathrm{and}\ \alpha\in\mathcal{L}_0\\
&\Rightarrow \alpha\in T_0
\end{align*}
$$

$T_0$ is a subset both of $T$ and of $\mathcal{L}_0$. The monotonicity of $\vDash$ states that if $X\vDash\alpha$ for some set of formulas $X$, then $X'\vDash\alpha$ for $X'\supseteq X$.

The other direction, $\alpha\in T_0\Rightarrow T_0\vDash\alpha$, is obvious.